# How to create an "Export to Excel" button compatible with IE7 in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, internet-explorer-7, export-to-excel

I'm editing some codes that control a database website using PHP, Javascript, and MySQL, and I'd like to add a button function that would allow me to export my data into an Excel file. Currently, the function below works for Firefox only--how do I create a function that would be compatible with Internet Explorer? I know that in IE8 I can simply right click and select "Export to Microsoft Excel", but for some reason in IE7, there is no option to do that, which is why I'm making this button.

Function for Firefox:

```
function write_to_excel(tableid) {
    var table=document.getElementById(tableid);
    var html=table.outerHTML;
    window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel.' + encodeURIComponent(html);
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There's a couple of problems in your code: the separator between the mime type and the encoded data should be a comma, not a period, and the closing bracket for `window.open` is missing.

Comment: Hm, for some reason I copy pasted it wrong. But this code only works for Firefox and doesn't work for Internet Explorer

Comment: [According to MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc848897%28VS.85%29.aspx) only IE8 and above support data URIs, and then with restrictions on their type. To directly quote [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/data_URIs#Support_in_other_browsers) "Internet Explorer 8 and above only supports data URIs for images in CSS, <link>, and <img>.". [Can I Use](http://caniuse.com/datauri) also lists IE 8-11 as "partial support".